# Thread-safe Rails controller actions - setting instance variables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety

I have to write a threaded Rails app because I am running it atop of Neo4j.rb, which embeds a Neo4j graph database inside the Rails process, and thus I have to serve multiple requests from the same process.  Yeah, it'd be cool if connecting to a Neo4j database worked like SQL databases, but it doesn't, so I'll quit complaining and just use it.

I'm quite worried about the implications of writing concurrent code (as I should be), and just need some advice on how to handle common a common scenario - a controller sets an instance variable or a variable in the session hash, then some stuff happens.  Consider the following crude code to demonstrate what I mean:

```
# THIS IS NOT REAL PRODUCTION CODE
# I don't do this in real life, it is just to help me ask my question, I
# know about one-way hashing, etc.!

class SessionsController
  def create
    user = User.find_by_email_and_password(params[:email], params[:password])
    raise 'auth error' unless user
    session[:current_user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to :controller => 'current_user', :action => 'show'
  end
end

class CurrentUserController
  def show
    @current_user = User.find(session[:current_user_id])
    render :action => :show # .html.erb file that uses @current_user
  end
end
```

The question: Are there any race conditions in this code?

In SessionsController, are the `session` hash and the `params` hash thread-local?  Say the same browser session makes multiple requests to /sessions#create (to borrow Rails route syntax) with different credentials, the user that is logged in should be the request that hit the line `session[:current_user_id] = user.id` last?  Or should I wrap a mutex lock around the controller action?

In the CurrentUserController, if the show action is hit simultaneously by two requests with different sessions, will the same @current_user variable be set by both?  I.e. will the first request, as it is processing the .html.erb file, find that it's @current_user instance variable has suddenly been changed by the second thread?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Each request gets a [new instance of your controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#methods-and-actions). As a consequence controller instance variables are thread safe. `params` and `session` are also backed by controller instance variables (or the request object itself) and so are also safe.

Comment: This is an old thread, sorry . But I've a follow up. That makes a lot of sense (and why people don't worry about @variables in controller methods. However if that's true, I'm confused at how this guy every had problems with his counter http://tenderlovemaking.com/2012/06/18/removing-config-threadsafe.html

Comment: @OliverShaw in that post counter is a class instance variable (because it is in the `class << self` block), so all the requests would be modifying the same counter

Comment: Coming back to Ruby. I'd remembered class variables, but not class instance variables. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's important to know what is shared between threads and what isn't.

Now back to your specific example. Two requests hit `CurrentUserController#show` simultaneously, hence they are handled by two concurrent threads. The key here is that each thread has its own instance of `CurrentUserController`, so there are two `@current_user` variables which don't interfere. So there's no race condition around `@current_user`.

An example of race condition would be this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_each :set_current_user
  cattr_accessor :current_user

  def set_current_user
    self.class.current_user = User.find_by_id(session[:current_user_id])
  end
end

# model
class LogMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.log_action(attrs)
    log_message = new(attrs)
    log_message.user = ApplicationController.current_user
    log_message.save
  end
end
```

On more general note, because of GIL (Global Interpreter Lock) benefits from using threads in MRI ruby are rather limited. There are implementation which are free from GIL (jruby).

Comment: Thanks for the example, however I already know that class variables would cause a race.  On the GIL issue, I think you're wrong - Ruby 1.9 threads are native, and I'm using JRuby anyway.

Comment: I'm glad you're on the right path. As for MRI ruby 1.9: it has native threads and GIL, which is global mutex used by those native threads.