# Is it dangerous to use instance variables of controller with jruby on rails and with multi-thread supporting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, jruby, mt

This is a question about MT safe on jruby on rails.

I just want to confirm that there is no MT safe issue to use controller instance variable.

In fact, the same question is that for each http request, rails will spawn a controller instance to process it or rails will reuse the same controller instance with different threads(just like servlet instance)?

I.E.,If one controller instance for one http request, then controller instance variable has NO MT safe issue,

If more than one thread share one controller instance, then controller instance variable has MT safe issue

Another similar questions is [Thread-safe Rails controller actions - setting instance variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12003714/thread-safe-rails-controller-actions-setting-instance-variables)

Comment: What further information would you like besides the answer in the other question?

Comment: In fact, I don't think we get the confirmed answer from the other question.

Comment: It wouldn't be any more 'confirmed' if I copied my answer from that question to this one.

Comment: Sorry, seems I missed Frederick Cheung's reply on the similar question(I focus on Jruby, instead of MRI). Your answer is what I want. Thanks.